# image File is not saving into Server "Img" Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SavePhoto(string base64)
{
    string file = "test.jpg";
    string Imgpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Img/"), Path.GetFileName(file));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Imgpath, Convert.FromBase64String(base64));

    return Json(new { status= true},JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

I make a request from Postman and send a Base64 string to the calling Action it's return **"true"** and Image saving locally but no Image has been saved to the server **"Img"** *Folder*. If there is no issue with my code then why Image is not saving into the server **"Img"** *Folder*

Comment: do you have write permission on server for that folder for that IIS user ?

Comment: how to write permissions...?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849554/createdirectory-at-server-in-a-shared-machine/26850094#26850094

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar no its not working....Actually I want to store image into server folder "Img". The image is storing on my local computer but not storing into server folder "Img". Please Help me with a 100% suitable answer

Comment: are you getting any error or exception ? 100% problem is permission only

Comment: no exception or error ocurrs image is saving into database but not saving into my server "Img" Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This

```
public JsonResult SavePhoto(string base64)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        string filestoragename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpeg";
        string outputPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Img/" + filestoragename);
        image.Save(outputPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return Json(new { status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

    }
```

Make sure you have created Img folder in your project solution

You need to use these references

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Web.Http;
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Img/" + filestoragename). There is an error line saying Error 3 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am already using these References But Still Getting the error. My Added references are...

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Shared;
using Donation.DataLayer;
using AdminModel;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

Comment: The Error Is........System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Replace that line with string outputPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Img/" + filestoragename);

Comment: now the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() error is gone but.... also the problem is same as I mentioned into my question that the Image is saving into my database and also into my local computer but not saving into my Project solution Folder with name "Img"

Comment: Then that's working fine...if you can see the image in your img folder in windows explorer..then that's that's working.. however it will not show in your visual studio solution folder..no need to worry abt this...even in servers it will work like this...if you have doubt just browse the path http://localhost:port/img/yourfilename.jpg

Comment: its working not only fine but excellently. you are great. Thanks a lot. I will Vote this

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code, its working fine in my project

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SavePhoto(string base64)
    {
        string fileName = "test.jpg";
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Employee/");
        string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + fileName;

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        var fs = new FileStream(path + "/" + uniqueFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();

        return Json(new { status = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```